# Most efficient way to write a buffer

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have to write an audio buffer that is filled/read progressively.

For now i'm using

```
m_outputBuffer.erase(
            m_outputBuffer.begin(),
            m_outputBuffer.begin()+read_samples);
```

when `read_samples` samples have been read from the buffer (I have to clear it to free RAM).
But I know `erase()` is very expensive so what alternative do I have, considering I basically only have to move the pointer to the first element of my buffer and free the beginning ?

Comment: Unclear, opinion based. Your question is futile.

Comment: *I have to clear it to free RAM* -- If that's a `std::vector`, calling `erase` doesn't free any RAM.

Comment: The std::deque is a container that is designed with efficient insertion and deletion of elements also at the beginning of the sequence.

Comment: There is no "most efficient" way to do things outside of very specific context.    Write working code and benchmark.  If it's too slow, identify why.

Comment: Constant reallocating memory is going to be a performance hit. Why can't you keep the buffer for multiple reads? For temporary buffers, just make an array on the stack (zero allocation cost) and it will clear itself up at the end of the scope.

Comment: The idea is that the "reader" doesnt read the whole buffer, so I have to keep the end (unread) of the buffer. It's not a temporary buffer, it's basically a FIFO queue. I'll try to see if I can use a deque, thanks :)

Comment: Then use a start and end of buffer pointer, like Malcolm McLean suggests, but don't bother changing to `C` there is absolutely no reason for that. A `deque` will be constantly allocating more memory and may not deallocate memory as much as you'd like (it could grow much larger than the amount you actually use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm still using

```
m_outputBuffer.erase(
            m_outputBuffer.begin(),
            m_outputBuffer.begin()+read_samples);
```

as it's really efficient : the erasing is done in one chunk, and the data left is relocated at the beginning of my vector, thus no pointer changes.

Answer (score 1):

`std::deque` appears to be a container that's best suited for something like this. `std::deque` is a random access container, like `std::vector`, but has (amortized) constant insertion and deletion complexity at the beginning of the container, unlike `std::vector` (and at the end of the container as well).

Comment: amortized time is great when N is huge.   In practice, N is usually not that large and vector is often better.

Comment: The size may be some hundreds, maybe some thousands. But I'll see if I can use the deque.

Answer (score -3):

Don't use C++ for this. Write it in C, which is of course also a subset of C++.

The buffer consists of a region of memory, and two pointers, one to the start position, one to the end. When data comes in, you add it to the end pointer, until you wrap. When data goes out, you increment the read pointer. You never need to delete or erase data. If the buffer overflows, likely that means something has gone wrong and you need to shut down the system - expanding it will just prolong the crash process.

Comment: C is not a subset of C++. They are two languages with a similar syntax. That is all. C++ can *sometimes* compile C code, but the results are typically inferior, just as applying C++ thinking and logic to C produces suboptimal C.

Comment: I agree with the basic idea behind this answer, but I find it incomprehensible that you think this is related to the choice of language. I also disagree about never growing the buffer. But this is the only answer which gets at the OP's problem. You have a buffer ... therefore you are by definition not supposed to be allocating or deallocating anything, as a part of normal operation.

Comment: An audio buffer is a very low-level data structure. Whilst you can use C++ STL if you know what you are doing, it's a distraction to an experienced programmer and a source of confusion to a less experienced one, as shown by the OP. Basically you want to implement the structure from bit level up and take control of every operation.

Comment: It's just not adapted to my use : I don't know in advance how many frames will be asked. It may be 10 or 10 000.

Comment: In which case the system will break down. Audio buffers exist to buffer balanced input / output requests so they are always honoured. If the requests vary so wildly, it's unlikely that any system is going to keep your audio DACs supplied with a constant stream of data at 44.1K samples per second.